# Streaming data Google Bigquery: tables

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Would there be a way to activate **streaming data** and save it in a new dataset?

That is, could we have an Analytics property that would **transfer the data into 2 different bigquery datasets**, one of which was streaming?

On the other hand, I understand from these two links: [link1](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038) and [link2](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2017/09/new-streaming-google-analytics-data-for.html) that activating streaming data implies **intraday tables dissapear**. Is it right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only link one export per property/view to a single dataset. Maybe, if you contact your Google rep and ask them nicely, they could send it to two. What's the reason for doing this anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @GrahamPolley. The reason is because a customer wants to set up two datasets in Bigquery from the same property: one for streaming data and the other one containing diary/intraday tables.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's currently possible. Maybe ask GA support?